# How do I disable the beep that emits from my PC when I am installing Debian?

Tags: linux, debian

Each time the PC boots and I pop in the Debian DVD into the DVD tray, it emits a blaring sound. I know the sound is emitting from the speaker inside of the PC but short of pulling it out or disable it via the BIOS, can I disable it in any other way as no sounds are heard when I boot with say Fedora, Ubuntu, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pc speaker is usually being handled by a kernel module named **pcspkr**. To unload this module manually you can try

```
modprobe -r pcspkr
```

Of course, you need to do it as root (or through sudo).

To make this persistent, you could add the line

```
blacklist pcspkr
```

to a file in **/etc/modprobe.d/**

Disabling the pc speaker from BIOS is probably overkill, since those BIOS beeps are a valuable source of information when debugging hardware issues.

Comment: Thanks. How do I unload the module before the Debian installation menu is presented as the sound emitted occurs as soon as the DVD boots?

Answer (score 0):

The kernel param equivalent of blacklisting through a modprobe config file on disk is:

```
 modprobe.blacklist=pcspkr
```

If the bootloader of the CD allows passing additional kernel params you could try passing this.